# Why can't I pass function evaluation as constructor parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was wondering why I can't pass a function evaluation as constructor parameter, i.e.:

```
A a(fstream(argv[1]))
```

if I try to call `a.dump()`, I get an error.

If I use

```
fsrteam fin(argv[1]);
A a(fin);
```

That works just fine.

The constructor is declared as

```
A(std::fstream &file)
```

Comment: I'd bet the error you're keeping so super-secret is pretty informative  toward answering your question (and I concur with the above, that it is an MVP).

Comment: How is the constructor declared?

Comment: @EdS: Seriously doubt this is MVP. `argv[1]` is not (ever) a type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bb004535bb6526d). `a` is a function taking an array (pointer) of 1 `std::fstream` (the parameter name shadows `argv`) and returning an `A`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for this. It seems like this is a form of MVP, but I'm still not 100% clear. You said `a is a function taking an array (pointer)`. Is that correct? it seems like fstream is taking an array. Right?

Comment: @chris: That looks like a bug, not MVP. The array parameter lacks a type. `argv[1]` is an _expression_. I'll look more into it.

Comment: @chris: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21624880/560648 My bad :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Many thanks for explaining this. This makes sense now, after reading the above mentioned question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have declared a() as follows:

```
A a(std::fstream &out);
```

This function a() takes a reference to a *mutable* (non-const) std::fstream.  But, your code:

```
A a(fstream(argv[1]));
```

constructs a *temporary* std::fstream as part of the expression that is the function call to a().  C++ will not permit a temporary object to be used as an argument to a function taking a non-const reference.

The rationale for this rule is that the non-const-ness of the reference implies that the function wants to change the referred to object.  Any changes to a temporary constructed in this way are "lost" in the sense that they are discarded when the temporary object is destroyed, as the function call expression finishes.  So, this case is often a logical error, and the rule aims to "fail safe" and disallow it.

In your second case, the fin variable isn't a temporary, so there the rule doesn't apply.

Comment: +1: Not a bad introduction to Stack Overflow, whatsoever. Welcome! _(edit: bah; two years?!)_

Comment: Long time lurker ;)  Decided I should answer some questions :)

Comment: Well from the looks of it I'm glad you did :)