# How does this declaration invoke the Most Vexing Parse?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

Consider the following program:

```
#include <fstream>

struct A {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a(std::fstream(argv[1]));
}
```

Clang in C++1y mode reckons that the MVP is invoked such that [`a` is parsed as a function declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/393a356e98041cf2):

```
clang++ -std=c++1y -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

main.cpp:6:8: warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]

    A a(std::fstream(argv[1]));

       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

main.cpp:6:9: note: add a pair of parentheses to declare a variable

    A a(std::fstream(argv[1]));

        ^

        (                    )
```

I understand the MVP, but not in this instance: `argv[1]` is clearly an expression, and there's no type before it, so how could this line be parsed as a function declaration?

Is it that the semantic interpretation on `argv[1]`, that would disambiguate the line as an object declaration, doesn't occur until after the compiler has already chosen to parse the line as a function declaration? Or is it a Clang bug? Or is it perfectly normal through some interpretation of the tokens `argv [ 1 ]` that I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's being parsed as

```
A a(std::fstream argv[1]);
```

i.e. a function that takes in an array of 1 `std::fstream`, where the extra parentheses are redundant.

Of course, in reality, that array parameter decays to a pointer, so what you end up with *semantically* is:

```
A a(std::fstream* argv);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, that's it. I _always_ miss this case! Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for this but.. does it even make sense to declare a function there in main() ? Why is clang being confused?

Comment: @Jarod42: Or, in fact, `std::fstream* argv`

Comment: @DavidKernin Block-scope declarations of functions are perfectly valid and have been since before the first standards of C and of C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it was most to correct the wording: "function that takes in an array of **1** std::fstream".

Comment: Feel free to correct the wording if it bothers you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Generally speaking, agreed, but I have seen (very old) C code where each function declares all other (non-standard) functions it uses locally, instead of using header files in the project. I can imagine that it made sense at the time, if the local declarations caused a measurable increase in compilation speed.

Comment: -1. this part is wrong >> `a function that takes in an array of 1 std::fstream`. The parameter is NOT an array, it is a pointer!

Comment: @Nawaz: Sheesh, if it bothers you *that much* then why don't you just fix it to your liking, like I'd already invited you to do? I wrote it that way because that was the only somewhat-logical wording I could think of with the number "1" in it, which is part of the signature. I didn't even downvote you for calling parentheses "braces", but if we're nitpicking so much maybe I should have...

Comment: @Mehrdad: *"Sheesh, if it bothers you that much then why don't you just fix it to your liking, like I'd already invited you to do?"* ... Ask yourself. Anyway, what you said, is NOT just a matter of vocabulary; **it is plain wrong fundamentally**. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: "Ask yourself"...? I'm asking you, it's not me whom it's bothering. Way to destroy a fine answer by nitpicking...

Comment: @Mehrdad: So you think, `T a[1];` and `T *a;` are same? Nothing wrong with that? You think the difference is pointless? How can it be pointless especially when one of them is a pointer? :P

Comment: @Nawaz: No, one of them is a pointer and the other is an array of size 1. In this case the parameter was declared to be an array of size 1.

Comment: @Mehrdad: The parameter is NOT an array. Period. (Anyway, I give up).

Comment: @Nawaz: Uh, would you enlighten me as to when when it *would* be an array, in your opinion? Don't give up so easily, you've already dragged me into this so you might as well take it till the end.

Comment: @Mehrdad: A parameter can NEVER be an array. It can at most be a *reference* to an array, e.g : `A a(std::fstream (&argv)[1]);`. Here `argv` is *a reference* to an array of size 1.

Comment: @Nawaz: A parameter can be an array (it's just a placeholder and you can declare it as such, no problem), but an argument can't (since an argument is a value, and values get passed around, but arrays can't be passed around).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks for saving the day. :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: *A parameter can, an argument can't.*. SHOW ME!

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, seriously, show me that *"A parameter can, an argument can't"*. I know what you say does NOT make sense!

Comment: @Nawaz The whole point of the decay is to convert an *array parameter* to a *pointer argument*. I think Mehrdad is correct here.

Comment: @Nawaz: _"`[C++11: 8.3.5/5]:` After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively."_ This means that the parameter starts off as `T[N]`, is changed to `T*`, and after that the argument can of course only take the type `T*` because that's what the parameter type has become.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Yes. If it decays, how can it be an array? It is like saying "alive people are buried by certain christians and muslims." No  they're NOT alive. They're dead. Likewise, parameter type can never an array; if you declare it an array, it WILL decay **in order to** become the parameter type!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So what is the parameter type? pointer or array? My answer is : "pointer". Your answer seems to be "array, but well, it then decays into a pointer, so it is an array and then pointer ... and pointer but it was an array anyway" :P. The point is simple: the compilers may do whole lots of stuffs before giving your the final product, it is their job; the intermediate things are NOT what the type is! For the programmers, the parameter type is : pointer!

Comment: @Nawaz: No, my answer is precisely what I told you, and what the standard says. It's fruitless debating with you because you're debating with the standard, so I shall stop now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I said that Mehrdad's statement *"a function **that takes** in an array of 1 std::fstream"* is wrong. Do you dispute that?

Comment: @Nawaz: Honestly, just, stop. I clarified his answer and that's the end of it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Alright. *"a function **that takes** in an array of 1 std::fstream"*. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The parens are superfluous. All of the following are the declarations:

```
T a;
T (a);
T ((a));
T (((a))));
```

so are these:

```
T a[1];
T (a[1]);
T ((a[1]));
T (((a[1]))));
```

So is this:

```
 A a(std::fstream(argv[1]));
```

which is same as:

```
 A a(std::fstream argv[1]);
```

which is same as:

```
 A a(std::fstream *argv);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: These are not braces.

Comment: These are not braces, and none of those invoke the MVP because you don't name a type for that hypothetical single parameter. I'd even go so far as to say that this property of parentheses _in this context_ isn't proof of much, since argument expressions could easily have different rules from parameter lists.

Comment: I'm not saying the declaration of `T a;` invokes MVP. That is used to explain the superfluous role of parens!

Comment: I understand, but since argument lists could behave differently from parameter lists, it doesn't really proove anything about the question. Even though, as it turns out, they _don't_ behave differently ;) I'm just being picky.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm NOT saying it is proof. Please don't read what I don't say :P... the purpose of the various declarations is to demonstrate the fact that the behavior *extra parens* is same even in simple declarations! ... and again it is said, because simple declarations are easy to remember, so it helps me (or programmers like me) to understand complex declarations.