# Why can function call operator on temporary objects sometimes be interpreted as a declaration that does not shadow a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is similar to [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034742/construction-of-temporary-in-function-call-is-interpreted-as-declaration), but with one big difference.

If I try to compile the following,

```
void test(string x){
  int x = 5;
  cout << x << endl;
}
```

I get the expected warning:

```
In function ‘void test(std::__cxx11::string)’:
error: declaration of ‘int x’ shadows a parameter
    int x = 5;
        ^
```

---

Now to get to the meat of my question; if I have a type with a function call operator like the following:

```
struct foo{
  string bar;
  foo(const string& bar) : bar(bar) { }
  void operator()(){
    cout << "my bar is \"" << bar << '"' << endl;
  }
};
```

I can create a temporary object and call its `()` operator with `foo("this will print")();` or with `foo{"this will also print"}();`

If I try to do the following, I will get a compiler error which is expected and can be explained with the post I linked above.

```
void redeclaration_error(){
  string x("lol");
  foo(x)();
}
```

However, things get weird here:

```
void hmm1(string str){
  foo(str)();
}
void hmm2(string str){
  foo{str}();
}
```

While `hmm2` will print out its argument when called, `hmm1` will do absolutely nothing. This is expected, as `hmm1`'s body does nothing more than declare `str` to be of type `foo`. However, in the scope of `hmm1`, `str` is already declared as type `string` from the function's parameter, so why does this not result in a compiler error like `error: declaration of ‘foo str‘ shadows a parameter`?

I understand that the compiler is interpreting `foo(str)();` as a declaration, and that lines like `foo(str).operator()();` and `(foo(str))();` will be interpreted as creating a temporary foo object and calling their function call operator, but why it it okay to declare a variable with the same name as a parameter in this circumstance?

---

[Here's and Ideone link where I was playing around with this.](https://ideone.com/dnm556)

Comment: Looks like gcc's bug, clang issues an error: https://godbolt.org/z/ECiUdI

Comment: MSVC also rejects it.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for testing it out on other compilers for me, I should have tried that too. I guess I trust gcc more than I should

Comment: You should report this, looks definitely like a bug

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu I'll do that as soon as soon as GCC Bugzilla gets back to me about creating an account. Also, can I mark a post as solved without having received an answer?

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question,  if you've concluded it's a bug and nobody wrote an answer yet then you can post that in the answer box

Comment: @M.M gotcha. So should I just answer my own question and mark it as solved? That just seems like an odd thing to do

Comment: That's a fairly normal thing to do if the people who answered answered in comments instead of posting an answer :)

Comment: Although I am not convinced about the supposed rule that a variable declared in the function body cannot have the same name as a function parameter  , the standard does not seem to say that (perhaps a separate question would be in order there)

Comment: @M.M I'll look into it more, but I checked an old working draft of the C++ standard, and found the following: ["A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a function-try-block" (3.3.2)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2691.pdf). This makes me pretty certain it is a GCC bug, unless there have been changes to the standard in this area since this draft

Comment: @JeffreyCash Ah that looks correct

Comment: OK, I posted an answer based on the comments and marked it as 'community' accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler program to produce the same issue (the extra parentheses are a red herring):

```
void f(int x)
{
    void x();
}
```

This is incorrect because of C++17 [basic.scope.block]/2:

> [...] A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function
>   definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a *function-try-block.*

If a compiler accepts this code then it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Awesome job distilling it down to its simplest form! I'll file a bug report as soon as I can. I'm amazed this has been in GCC for so long, it's been in every version I've checked between 4.4.7 and 8.3